# Missing table in SQL after conecting by C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have instaled SQL Server on mi pc, then create database and table:

```
Create database DatabaseX;

CREATE TABLE MainTable
(
Product varchar(255),
ProductDescription varchar(255),
ProductPrce int
);
```

and add sime info to it, when I'm working in SQL Managmend Studio I log in by windows autentication. So I created WPF to conect this database:

```
    try
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=" + DatabaseUsernameTextBox.Text + ";" +
                   "password=" + DatabasePasswordTextBox.Text + ";server=" + DatabaseServerTextBox.Text + ";" +
                   "Trusted_Connection=" + DatabaseTrustedConectionComboBox.SelectedItem + ";" +
                   "database=" + DatabaseNameTextBox.Text + "; " +
                   "connection timeout=" + DatabaseConectionTimeouTextBox.Text + "");

        myConnection.Open();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Conection by: localhost, DatabaseX works, there is no exception, but.... whatever I paste as user id and password it always conect, don't exackly geting how? So conection is on but when I try to:

```
 SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from MainTable;", myConnection);

                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myReader["ProductName"].ToString());
                    //Console.WriteLine(myReader["Column2"].ToString());
                }
```

There is exception that "Invalid object name 'MainTable'." any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell from the code above, but it sounds like you created the table on your master database.

You may just need to add a USE statement prior to creating the table:

```
Create database DatabaseX;

use database DatabaseX;

CREATE TABLE MainTable
(
Product varchar(255),
ProductDescription varchar(255),
ProductPrce int
);
```

Another option is to specify the database name in your table create:

```
CREATE TABLE DatabaseX.dbo.MainTable
    (
    Product varchar(255),
    ProductDescription varchar(255),
    ProductPrce int
    );
```

Have you tried locating the table in Management Studio?

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well. Connection context in management studio is still the master db.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're connected to the server but perhaps not the correct database. Have you tried setting initial catalog?